# print variables that contain an array of numbers by columns

Tags: arrays, bash, awk, sed

I gather an array of numbers like this

```
values=`sed -n "3,6p" STAT_EE/table_EE'.tex' | awk '{ print $4}'`

val=`sed -n "8,12p" STAT_EE/table_EE'.tex' | awk '{ print $4}'`
```

and then I want to print this to variables in columns. I tried with `echo -en "$values\t$val` but it prints the two variables as a one single array I also tried with printf but it did not work.

Could you please help me with this concern? Thank's a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the variables that you have defined are not bash arrays; they are bash strings.  To make arrays, enclose the expressions in parentheses:

```
values=(`sed -n "3,6p" STAT_EE/table_EE'.tex' | awk '{ print $4}'`)    
val=(`sed -n "8,12p" STAT_EE/table_EE'.tex' | awk '{ print $4}'`)
```

To print them out in two columns:

```
for ((i=0;i<${#values[@]};i++))
do
    echo "${values[i]}  ${val[i]}"
done
```

or:

```
for i in $( seq 0 $((${#values[@]}-1)) )
do
    echo "${values[i]}  ${val[i]}"
done
```

#### Advanced Topics

Because the backtick notation is fragile and does not nest well, the `%(...)` construct is generally preferred.  Also, in the `sed-awk` code above, `sed` is only being used to select and range of lines.  That is something that `awk` does very well.  So, the code can simplify to:

```
values=( $(awk 'NR>=3 && NR<=6{ print $4}' STAT_EE/table_EE.tex) )
val=( $(awk 'NR>=8 && NR<=12{ print $4}' STAT_EE/table_EE.tex) )
```

Comment: You don't need sed with awk and its best to avoid deprecated backtick syntax: `values=( $(awk 'NR>=3 && NR<=6{ print $4}' STAT_EE/table_EE'.tex') )`

Comment: Thank you John1024. I really appreciate your help :). 
Thanks for the additional comments Ed Morton :).